# 'NoneType' object is not callable: BeautifulSoup HTML parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse an HTML table in a webpage, which I passed to BeautifulSoup as a string input. I have given the following script to parse the HTML page and print the contents in a CSV file:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(In_put)
comments = soup.find_all('td', {"id": "TicketDetails_TicketDetail_TicketDetail__ctl0_Tablecell1"})
f = open(Out_put, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for s in comments:
    writer.writerow(s.split('##'))
f.close()
```

But it shows an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KOS974/PycharmProjects/test_cases/gasper_try.py", line 561, in <module>
    writer.writerow(s.split('##'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I am really not able to understand why the error is coming, even after there is some content in the `<tr>` tag with the same `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the method `.split()` on BeautifulSoup `Element` instances.

Such objects do not *have* a `.split()` method, but they do try and search for any attribute that they don't recognize. `element.split` is translated to `element.find('split')`, but there is no `<split>` tag to be found and `None` is returned. Since you used `element.split()`, you end up with `None()` instead, and that fails.

You want to extract the *text* from each element first:

```
for s in comments:
    writer.writerow(s.get_text().split('##'))
```